# Using money-rails minidollars unit instead of cents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, money-rails

By default, money save value in cents and create migration like price_cents:integer. I need to save and calculate values in minidollars (1/1000 of currency).

I don't register currencies myself. 
I use gem google_currency for getting current currency rates.

How can i set precision 1/1000 for all money values?

```
  * rails (4.2.1)
  * money (6.5.1)
  * money-rails (1.4.1)
  * google_currency (3.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Rubymoney/money), you can register your own subunit:

```
curr = {
  :priority        => 1,
  :iso_code        => "USD",
  :iso_numeric     => "840",
  :name            => "United States Dollar",
  :symbol          => "$",
  :subunit         => "Minidollar",
  :subunit_to_unit => 1000,
  :separator       => ".",
  :delimiter       => ","
}

Money::Currency.register(curr)
```

Google Currency just extends `Money::Bank::VariableExchange`, so now you'd do this to create a $1 item and get the value in Euros:

```
money = Money.new(10_00, "USD") # this is in "minidollars"
money.exchange_to(:EUR)
```